# TypeScript Error Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, types

I'm generally new to TypeScript and I'm receiving this error .

> Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Pick<PropsI, "loadUser" | "user">': loadUser, user

The above error is coming within App.text and pointing to `<AppRouter/>`

I'm confused to why I'm getting this and what the possible fix is? Im assuming I'm not declaring something correctly inside of the app router but I cant seem to figure out what's wrong or the error I'm recieving?

### App.tsx

```
import AppRouter from './router/AppRouter'

const App: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <AppRouter />
    </Fragment>
  )
}

export default App
```

#### App Router

```
import React, {ExoticComponent, Fragment, useEffect} from 'react'
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom'
import FreeTextView from '../components/analytics/dashboard/freeTextView/FreeTextView'
import {connect, useDispatch, useSelector} from 'react-redux'
import {Nav, IconSvgs} from '@pxhub/shared-components'
import {AppState, UserI, AccessRecordsI} from '../store/actions/Types'
import {loadUser} from '../store/actions/UserActions'

interface PropsI {
  loadUser: () => void
  user: UserI
}

// Defualt Page
const Page = () => {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/freeview" component={FreeTextView} />
      </Switch>
    </Fragment>
  )
}

// App Router
export const AppRouter: React.FC<PropsI> = ({loadUser, user}: PropsI) => {
  const userAccess = user.accessRecords.map((accessRecord: AccessRecordsI) => {
    return accessRecord.Access_Transaction
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    loadUser()
  })

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <IconSvgs />
      <Nav
        user={user}
        userAccess={userAccess}
        urlPrefix={process.env.REACT_APP_URL_PREFIX}
      />
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" component={Page} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </Fragment>
  )
}

const dispatch = useDispatch()

const mapDispatchToProps = () => () => {
  dispatch(loadUser())
}
const mapStateToProps = useSelector((state: AppState) => state.user)

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AppRouter)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declared AppRouter as requiring the props loaduser and user, but then you called it without those props in App.tsx.

EDIT: Although not the cause of the specific TS error identified in the question, as noted in the comments, it can also cause problems to combine `useSelector` and `mapStateToProps` or `useDispatch` and `mapDispatchToProps`.  These days you likely want to just use the hooks.

Comment: I get that, but I have props coming from redux?

Comment: Sure, but TS doesn't know that.  Take a look at this link (https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/static-typing#typing-the-connect-higher-order-component) for how to type `connect`.  But also, you may find it much easier these days (as I do!) to use useSelector instead of mapDispatchToProps.

Comment: @Jack also i think your redux configuration is wrong. you combined `useSelector` and `mapStateToProps` (they are alternatives and shouldn't combined together.). and `mapDispatchToProps` and `useDispatch` also.

Comment: good point. and, sorry, i meant useDispatch in my comment.  @yaya's point is correct about the equivalence.  side note: if you want to cross the bridge of using TS with redux (worth it, IMHO), redux tool kit makes that much easier, and this tutorial in particular: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/advanced-tutorial

Comment: @sam256 appreciate both of your help!

Comment: @yaya point is correct , we should not use [`useSelector` and `mapStateToProps`] together. I faced similar issue and this was the cause of the ts2740 warning. You should add it as an answer here

Comment: @sam256 regarding the last comment, can you please update your answer and add the `useSelector and mapStateToProps` bug also? thanks. (I'm a bit lazy to do it :p )

Comment: @yaya, i don't think that is the cause of OP's problem or directly responsive to the question, however I have edited to note it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the mapDispatchToProps syntax.

Should't it be something like this?

```
const mapDispatchToProps = () => {
  dispatch(loadUser())
}
```